# UIImagePickerController to take multiple pictures and save them in Document directory ony by one

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I need my app to provide users to click multiple pictures. I want a layout with two separate buttons, one for clicking picture and another for saving the picture taken in the document's directory of filesystem. This screen will be presented and UIImagePickerController will be opened.

When user clicks first button, we will disable this button and show the picture obtained in an overlay. And show another button(this will be enabled now) to save this picture.

When user clicks another button, we will disable this button and save it in filesystem. After saving successfully, we will again enable the first button to take more pictures.

I have tried and implemented this app and it works perfectly at our end. But our some users report of app crashing when UIImagePickerOriginalImage key returned is nil.

This doesn't even happen to them frequently. Instead they face this crash after a long usage of app. However, we have tried of taking more 200 pictures and saving too. It didn't lead to any crash.

Please anyone suggest what might be the cause for this crash. Or any other better workaround to implement this functionality.

Comment: Post some relevant code and point out where it is crashing and post the complete error message.

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648022/uiimagepickercontrollers-view-added-as-a-childview-to-another-controller?noredirect=1#comment47436533_29648022